# Examples of 2D CFT with global non-abelian gauge theories?

Tags: gauge-theory, conformal-field-theory, partition-function

I am looking for some examples of 2D CFT partition functions with global non-abelian gauge symmetry. Can someone give me some reference books/papers on it ? 
Also for 2D CFT with supersymmetry along with non-abelian gauge symmetry.

Comment: I am not sure that you can define gauge symmetries intrinsically in CFT terms. So CFT can have gauge symmetry only in the sense that there is a microscopic realization of it which possesses a gauge symmetry. For that, here is a SUSY example, they effective do compute the partition function: https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.5314 (to be precise, they study the IR fixed points of 2d SYM with matter)

Comment: To be honest, I can't understand what is "global gauge symmetry".

Comment: I meant you have examples of 2D CFT with U(1) global symmetry, I am hoping to find some examples of 2D CFT with SU(2) symmetry, or some SU(N) symmetry.